# When I try to integrate firebase into flutter 1.9.1 app runing in android and im geting the error sqfile

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Im trying to rum my aplication on android 9 after update to android 1.9.1 hotfix 6 and is continuing getingme the same error when I run the aplication

and I update all my dependencys and pluguins to the latest

this is all my configurations

this is my project yml dependecys

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.4.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_crashlytics: ^1.0.0
  rxdart: 0.22.2
  kiwi: ^0.2.0
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
  image_picker: ^0.6.1+4
  photo_view: ^0.5.0
  cached_network_image: ^1.1.1
  smooth_star_rating: ^1.0.2
  carousel_slider: ^1.3.1
  dio: ^2.1.0
  url_launcher: ^5.1.3
  webview_flutter: ^0.3.5+3
  flare_flutter: ^1.7.1
  geolocator: ^5.1.3
  path_provider: ^1.4.4
  sqflite: ^1.1.7+2
```

gradle version 6.0.1
android /build.gradle

```
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and keeps me saying this error and i have the latest version of sqflite

```
[        ] > Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED
[        ] Parsing json file: ***\code\mobile-app\android\app\google-services.json
[   +1 ms]          *********************************************************
[        ] WARNING: This version of sqflite will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
[        ]          See ..... for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
[        ]          This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
[        ]          *********************************************************
[        ] 42 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 38 up-to-date
```

Comment: Migrating your project to AndroidX might help

Answer (score 0):

> WARNING: This version of sqflite will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.

from this log error you can see that your app will break since the plugins are not compatible with androidX

you have to [migrate to androidX](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration)

latest versions of flutter require your app to be androidX enabled to run

Answer (score 0):

actually the error is the gradle file and android manifest mismatch